# Python: How does "IN" (for lists) works?

Tags: python, list, data-structures

I have this code

```
list = ['a','b','c']

if 'b' in list:
   return "found it"
return "not found"
```

Now, how does this work? Does it traverse the whole list comparing the element? Does it use some kind of hash function?

Also, is it the same for this code?

```
list.index('b')
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`in` uses the method `__contains__`. Each container type implements it differently. For a list, it uses linear search. For a dict, it uses a hash lookup.

Comment: Thanks, great answer. I'm new in Python and did not know about __contains__

Answer (score 7):

Python Wiki [states](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) that `val in list` has `O(n)` average time complexity. This implies linear search. I expect `list.index(val)` to be the same.

After all, `list` is, well, a list. If you want hash tables, consider using `set` or `dict`.

Answer (score 2):

The comparison is evaluated once for every item in the list.

See http://effbot.org/zone/python-list.htm for more information on Python lists (and list comprehensions as you have posted).

Answer (score 1):

Both `in` and `list.index()` loop over all elements and have therefore a linear runtime.  In addition to the intuitive logic (it has to be this way since a list is just a dynamic array), you can verify that by looking at the **C implementation** of [`list_contains`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3ff40811aeed/Objects/listobject.c#l397) (`in`) and [`listindex`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3ff40811aeed/Objects/listobject.c#l2132).

For example, the `__contains__` routine is implemented as simple as:

```
static int
list_contains(PyListObject *a, PyObject *el)
{
    Py_ssize_t i;
    int cmp;

    for (i = 0, cmp = 0 ; cmp == 0 && i < Py_SIZE(a); ++i)
        cmp = PyObject_RichCompareBool(el, PyList_GET_ITEM(a, i),
                                           Py_EQ);
    return cmp;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the disassembly:

```
>>> from dis import dis
>>> def foo():
...     a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
...     if 'b' in a:
...             print "Found it!"
... 
>>> dis(foo)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('a')
              3 LOAD_CONST               2 ('b')
              6 LOAD_CONST               3 ('c')
              9 BUILD_LIST               3
             12 STORE_FAST               0 (a)

  3          15 LOAD_CONST               2 ('b')
             18 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             21 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
             24 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       35

  4          27 LOAD_CONST               4 ('Found it!')
             30 PRINT_ITEM          
             31 PRINT_NEWLINE       
             32 JUMP_FORWARD             0 (to 35)
        >>   35 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             38 RETURN_VALUE
```

The in-operator calls __contains__ in the COMPARE_OP instruction. You can see it in action here:

```
class X(object):
    def __init__(self, elements):
        self.elements = elements
    def __contains__(self, element):
        print "Called __contains__"
        return element in self.elements

x = X(['a', 'b', 'c'])
if 'b' in x:
    print "Found it!"
```

You get this output:

```
...
>>> x = X(['a', 'b', 'c'])
>>> if 'b' in x:
...     print "Found it!"
... 
Called __contains__
Found it!
```

Comment: It's no secret that `in` causes `__contains__` to be called.  This does not answer the question how this is implemented for lists.

Comment: @Ferdinand: Interestingly, not everyone knows that, starting with OP ("Thanks, great answer. I'm new in Python and did not know about contains")

Comment: For built-in types, it does not matter which function `in` calls.  So, still, your "answer" does not answer this question.  Not at all.  Anyone who wants to add support for `in` in his own class should simply read the manual.  It explains the behavior of every operator in detail, this is why I said that it's not a secret.  There is no need to use the disassembler here!  By the way, the disassembler does not provide any helpful information -- there's an opcode that executes `in`, d'oh, we already see this in the original code!  The `__contains__` magic still happens "backstage".